# Treat RegEx operator as simple character in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Ok so I have a String which looks something like this
`[RandomChars] Name`
and I want to remove the
`[RandomChars]`
part of the String.

The problem I run in to is that regex treats the `[` and `]` as operators and not as characters.

I thought adding `\\` before the operators would make them act as characters but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is some sample code

```java
String strOriginal = "[TAS] ElDuko";

String changed = strOriginal.replaceAll("\\[\\D\\]", "");

System.out.println(changed);
```

Comment: You just needed to add `*` or `+`: `\\D*`.

Comment: `\\D` doesn't match `TAS`, hence, nothing is replaced. There are various sites where you can 'live' try regexes. I suggest you toy around with those and you'll figure it out soon enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
String changed = strOriginal.replaceAll("\\s*\\[[^\\]\\[]*]", "").trim();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9n70f/1) and mind the `.trim()` at the end.

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char (it is not special!)